# Best option to get selected item from spoken list?

Tags: dialogflow-es, actions-on-google

when the user has screen, it's easy to create list and then get the selected item, however, if they don't, it's a lot harder.

Simple scenario:

A: I have tablet, smartphone, computer.

B: phone

What's the best way to assign phone to smartphone, if the list is dynamic and I can't create entity for it?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

The best way is to try to come up with entities and define synonyms for each entity, so that Dialogflow can match what user had said.

Given that you can not create entities, your Action could list available options to your user and ask to pick one. You could explicitly make it clear that user should say the chosen option word-by-word. In your scenario:

A: I have tablet, smartphone, computer. Please tell me which one of those options you'd like.

B: Phone

A: Sorry, I am unable to understand this. You can only say "tablet", "smartphone", or "computer". Please tell me which one of those options you'd like.

I'd suggest taking a look at Conversation Design site for more guides on how to handle similar scenarios. In your case, [Disambiguation](https://designguidelines.withgoogle.com/conversation/conversational-components/questions.html#questions-critical-use-cases-for-narrow-focus-questions) section in the guide will be helpful.